# DataGridView, Change cell of a typed Column to another type

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcell

I'm trying to mix a column on a datagridview with 2 control types (Checkbox & TextBox), the data is coming from a Stored Procedure that I'm also writing so I have a little flexibility.

in the stored procedure I'm returning a blank column to act as a `Selection` column in the GridView, but I am encountering problems when trying to convert cells to the other type based on criteria......

I keep the problem is with the datatypes when converting between the control types, I have tried all sorts of different ways to convert value first, controls first, etc but nothing is working 100%.....

currently, I have the SP returning the string `False` in a column then in using this with the criteria to create a checkbox..... it works fine but the Value remains a string even after converting it to a `Boolean`, the datatype is also a `Boolean` on the checkbox but the value is `String`..... this has gone over my head now and I'm at a loss......

```
NewCntrl2 = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
NewCntrl2.Value = Convert.ToBoolean(DGV.Cells(0).Value)
NewCntrl2.ValueType = GetType(System.Boolean)
DGV.Cells(0) = NewCntrl2
```

this is the code converting the textbox-column cell to a checkbox cell

any ideas why the value of the checkbox is still a string ('False')...

the problem with what it's doing now is when I handle the cell click event I cannot check or uncheck the box using the `Not Value` technique

----EDIT----

This is the sub I'm using, it creates several different types of controls.

```
Public Sub posted_CreateControls()
    Dim Cell_0 As String
    Dim Cell_1 As String
    Dim Cell_2 As String
    Dim NewCntrl As DataGridViewButtonCell
    Dim NewCntrl2 As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

    For Each Rw As DataGridViewRow In dgvPosted.Rows

        With Rw

            Cell_0 = .Cells(1).Value.ToString
            Cell_1 = .Cells(2).Value.ToString
            Cell_2 = .Cells(3).Value.ToString


            'this column starts with a value 'False' returned by the SP, 
            'we don't want checkboxes on all rows and using false string was the only method
            'i could find to easily do this
            'if both assign and unassign id are present then we need a checkbox
            Select Case Cell_0
                Case String.Empty
                    .Cells(0).Value = String.Empty

                Case Else
                    If Not Cell_1 = String.Empty Then
                        NewCntrl2 = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
                        NewCntrl2.Value = Convert.ToBoolean(.Cells(0).Value)
                        NewCntrl2.ValueType = GetType(System.Boolean)
                        .Cells(0) = NewCntrl2
                    Else
                        .Cells(0).Value = String.Empty
                    End If

            End Select

            'Create an Assign button for each row in columnindex 0(Assign) if ColumnIndex(2)(Edit) contains M, L or I
            Select Case Cell_2
                Case "M", "L", "I", "P"
                    NewCntrl = New DataGridViewButtonCell
                    .Cells(1) = NewCntrl
                    NewCntrl.Tag = Cell_0
                    NewCntrl.Value = "Assign"
            End Select

            'Create an UnAssign button in columnindex 1(UnAssign) if the value of columnindex 1(Unassign) is not empty
            If Not Cell_1 = vbNullString Then
                NewCntrl = New DataGridViewButtonCell
                .Cells(2) = NewCntrl
                NewCntrl.Tag = Cell_1
                NewCntrl.Value = "UnAssign"
            End If

            'Create an Edit button on columnindex 2(Edit) if ColumnIndex 2(Edit) is not M, L or empty string
            Select Case Cell_2
                Case "M", "L", "P", vbNullString
                    'Do Nothing
                Case Else
                    NewCntrl = New DataGridViewButtonCell
                    .Cells(3) = NewCntrl
                    NewCntrl.Tag = Cell_2
                    NewCntrl.Value = "Edit"
            End Select
        End With
    Next

    NewCntrl = Nothing
End Sub
```

This creates the checkboxes how I want them but the values remain as a string that is causing the cell. Click event to fail because I'm trying to set the checkbox value to true and the `.value = not .value` part is failing because for some reason the value remains a string but the checkboxes value type is in fact Boolean.....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning false try returning:

```
`select CAST(0 as bit) as somefield`
```

Which will return a boolean field. I'd also recommend adding a check box column instead of adding the individual cells.

Comment: I also tried this but I came across the problem when I need to remove checkboxes from certain rows......not all rows should have them and I tried the revers .. changing checkbox cells to textbox cells but couldn't find a way to prevent the FormatValue error that it causes. however I did not try this with the code I gave above... I will try it and see if it works

Comment: I still go with the column approach, handle the cellformatting event to disable / enable any of the checkboxes / change the cell style to a normal textbox cell.

Comment: I need the cells to be completely blank, its not a standard table that is populated here and has empty rows to separate parent rows, and each parent row has multiple child rows and they also have child rows. however never mind the complicated nature of the table, my only problem now is that fact that when I change a cell control to another type its value types (although changing) still retain their old value.... how can type Boolean contain a value of String?.......no errors at all, I think I just missed something.

Comment: Can you post the code that is giving an issue as an edit, I'm finding your description a bit confusing.

Comment: I found a solution that seems to work, on the cell.click event I noticed the formatvalue is Boolean, so I just change the .value between the strings "False", and "True" and this seems  to work.......it seems odd that it works this way though